# A question on Euler's criterion for quadratic residues

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

In a proof in my lecture notes on number theory  for Euler's criterion, my lecturer asserts that if $a$ is a quadratic non residue then 
$$\forall c\in\{1,...,p-1\}\, \exists c'\in\{1,....,p-1\}\text{ s.t. }cc'\equiv a \pmod{p} \text{ with } c'\neq c.$$

Why is this so ?

Comment: Well, $c$ has a modular inverse $c'$, and if that $c'$ was equal to $a$, then $a$ would be a quadratic residue.

Comment: @darijgrinberg why should the inverse of $c$ be $c'$? If that was the case then by the congruence given $a\equiv1 \pmod{p}$.

Comment: $c'$ is just a name they give to the inverse.

Comment: @darijgrinberg but OP is using $c'$ to mean something else, that is why your hint may seem incorrect, even though I know what you are trying to convey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mbox{**A Solution Using Modular Arithmetic**}$$

Assuming $p$ is a prime number, we can say that $\gcd(c,p)=1$ and so there exists a multiplicative inverse of $c$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ say $c''$. Then define $$c'=ac''$$Therefore, it is easy to see that $c'\neq 0$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (because $p\nmid a$). Therefore, $$cc'\equiv c\cdot (ac'')\equiv(cc'')\cdot a\equiv a\pmod{p}$$which completes the proof.

**Note:** $c\neq c'$, else $$cc'\equiv c^2\equiv a\pmod{p}$$which contradicts that $a$ is a quadratic non residue.

**$$\mbox{**A Solution Using Division Algorithm**}$$**
Consider a number $c$ such that $\gcd(c,p)=1$. Therefore, there exists integers $c''$ and $k$ such that $$cc''-pk=1$$by [bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)
. Therefore, $$pk=cc''-1 \implies pka=acc''-a$$where $a$ is a QNR. It is easy to note that $\gcd(c'',n)=1\implies ac''\in\{1,2,\ldots,p-1\}$. We consider $c'=ac''$ and hence,$$p\mid cc'-a\implies cc'\equiv a\pmod{p}$$Since $a$ is a NQR, $c\ne c'$ which completes the proof.

Comment: you also need to show that $c \neq c'$ to complete the proof.

Comment: I don't think your added note answers my comment. You are supposed to prove that you can always make a choice of $c'$ such that $c \neq c'$. So what you need to show is that $c \neq ac''$.

Comment: @anand It wasn't so much how it fits into the proof I was hoping more for an argument that used the division algorithm so as to understand why we can always get a number a given two distinct c c' so long as a in NQR and p is prime, for instance the same truth doesn't hold in non prime mods I was wondering why its only under these specif conditions that its true ?

Comment: @AnuragA Well... that's exactly what I showed. Indeed, it is impossible that $c=ac''$ because if so happens, then $cc'=c^2$, but we have already shown that $cc'=a$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $a=c^2$ in the ring  $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ which contradicts the definition of $a$.

Comment: @excalibirr I am sorry, I don't follow your question. Do you want a proof that uses the division algorithm?

Comment: @Anand that would be great  If you wouldn't mind, I find it hard to follow when its it mod form unfortunately

Comment: @excalibirr I have written a solution that uses division algorithm.